# "With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call" in operators

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

There are at least 2 operators with similar texts in their description:

> With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the
>   operation of an **< operator >** is a single evaluation.

Where **< operator >** might be either "compound assignment" ([expr.ass]) or "postfix ++" ([expr.post.incr]). That rule, if understand correctly, states essentially that the any interleaving (overlapping) between the indeterminately-sequenced function call and one of the aforementioned operator is forbidden. But the Standard already forbids it in [intro.execution]p15:

> <...> Evaluations A and B are indeterminately sequenced when either A
>   is sequenced before B or B is sequenced before A, but it is
>   unspecified which. [ Note: Indeterminately sequenced evaluations cannot overlap, but either could be executed first. — end note ] <...>

So to the question: is the wording in the operator description redundant and might as well be removed completely? And if it is not redundant please describe a situation when the text from the operators apply but the general rule does not.

Answer (score 0):

The execution of the postfix increment occurs in **two** steps: first, an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied, then, at some point before the end of the full-expression, the value stored in the object is incremented. The latter step is sequenced after the former.

Let's say A is sequenced before B, and both A and B are indeterminately sequenced with C. In that case, no pair of A, B, and C may overlap, however, there are three possible execution orders: ABC, ACB, and CAB.

In the case of the postfix increment, the additional guarantee provided by the language is that the order can only be ABC or CAB. A function call will never occur *between* the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and the side effect.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I follow you completely. What allows you to convert a single postfix increment into 2 expressions? Yes, I completely understand that it is a 2 step process but from the language POV it is a single expression and for this expression we have an order of value computation & side effect, not 2 sub-expressions. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ixSci Nowhere does the standard promise that executing one operator only produces a single *evaluation*. According to [intro.execution], it is evaluations that are sequenced, not expressions.

Comment: There are no 2 evaluations in the increment operator either. There is only one evaluation which is value computation and start of side effects.

Comment: @ixSci If that were the case, then the standard would already be contradicting itself by saying "the value computation of the ++ expression is sequenced before the modification of the operand object"; your interpretation is not the correct one.

Comment: Well, let's put it aside (I do not agree with you on this one but it is no really relevant, just look a the evaluation description in the same section it is a value computation and start of side effects). The Standard regulates not only evaluations but expressions also: _"An expression X is said to be sequenced before an expression Y if every value computation and every side effect associated with the expression X is sequenced before every value computation and every side effect associated with the expression Y"_. It is in the same section and paragraph I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ixSci OK, you're right, that text was added in C++17. However, it doesn't matter. Clearly, when a complex expression is evaluated by the abstract machine, it can take place in multiple evaluations that may or may not be sequenced with respect to each other. So, looking at an expression such as `a++`, you may think that only one evaluation can be taking place, but the standard does not say any such thing.

Comment: Given `int x; int f(void) { x = 1; return 1; }`, does this rule mean that `f() + ++x` is undefined behavior while `f() + x++` is not?

Comment: @GKxx No. It's guaranteed that a function call never interleaves with any other evaluations on the same thread (other than, potentially, a signal handler) so there is no UB in either case.